SeaweedInputStream: offset greater than length of array
I'm working in a system with concurrent editing active. Content is stored by SeaweedFS and when we perform repetitive write on the content, sometimes when we read all bytes
try(SeaweedInputStream in = new SeaweedInputStream(filerClient, filePath)){
            byte[] read = in.readAllBytes();
            ...

we got the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset greater than length of array
        at seaweedfs.client.SeaweedInputStream.read(SeaweedInputStream.java:96)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:412)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes(InputStream.java:349)

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
